# How to get 3 1900x1200 monitors working on a 2010 Mac Pro

Tags: macos, mac, graphics, mac-pro

I have a new Mac Pro with a single ATI 5770 card installed. It has two mini-display ports, and one DVI port

I have tried the following configurations:

1. All 3 DVI connections: This results in one monitor always being black
2. 2 Mini to 2 VGA and one DVI - This results in the VGA monitors having a max resolution of 1920x1080 but defaulting to 1600x1200 due to the aspect ratio. All monitors have a 1920x1200 resolution, but only the DVI port is giving this resolution
3. All 3 VGA with a DVI to VGA converter on the DVI port - Same result as #2. The monitor plugged into the DVI->VGA port has full resolution. The two Mini->VGA are limited to 1920x1080

My question:

Is this even possible without Apple's dual link adapters?

Comment: Also, there isn't a 2012 Mac Pro. The most recent one is updated a few years ago. There is a small speed bump, but even Apple refers it to mid-2010.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Apple's specs listed under [Tech Specs for the Mac Pro](http://www.apple.com/macpro/specs.html) it should be able to handle 3 displays at up to `2560 by 1600 pixels` over the digital connections. I think the trouble is coming from a little known about techology from AMD called [Eyefinity](http://www.amd.com/us/products/technologies/amd-eyefinity-technology/Pages/eyefinity.aspx). Which seems to require "Active" Adapters in order to run more than 2 displays at a time.

[According to AMD who makes the ATI 5770 card.](http://www.amd.com/us/products/technologies/amd-eyefinity-technology/for-consumers/Pages/what-is-eyefinity.aspx)

> **What are the basic requirements for connecting multiple displays?**
>
> Connecting multiple monitors for AMD Eyefinity technology couldn’t be simpler. There are four easy rules to remember:
>
> 1. The first two monitors can connect to the graphics card with any display output on your product: HDMI, VGA, DVI or DisplayPort.
> 2. The third (or greater) display must be connected to the graphics card via DisplayPort.
> 3. If your monitor does not have a DisplayPort connection, you will need an inexpensive active DisplayPort adapter for it. DVI to DP adapters can be had for less than $30 USD.2
> 4. Every family of GPUs supports a different maximum number of displays.

It looks like you may have the passive  adapters for  the MiniDP to DVI adapters. and hence the trouble and why only 2 displays work when all DVI. Note that the MiniDP to VGA are active adapters.

With the 1920 X 1200 resoultion you will be fine with Single Link adapters, you just need active mini display port to DVI adapters. For some guidance on obtaining compatible adapters see [AMD Eyefinity Validated Dongles](http://support.amd.com/us/eyefinity/Pages/eyefinity-dongles.aspx)

As noted in a [similar question in the Apple Store](http://store.apple.com/us/question/answers/product/MC742ZM/A?pqid=QA7KKPFDTD9JXT94P229UACFJA4C9D4UCKTTJHFAK27FT97KP):

> **Q:To use three monitors, does this work with the recently-available active single-link DP to DVI adapters (NOT the simple passive one that Apple [sold])?**
>
> Late last year, active single-link DVI adapters became available that function in the same way as the active dual-link adapter that Apple sells, but is intended for use with smaller, single-link monitors. These provide the same added intelligence that the dual-link adapters provide, but only support single-link resolutions. This makes them much cheaper (typically around $30) and they don't don't require the extra power of a USB port.
>
> Can these adapters be used with this card in a mid-2010 (5,1) Mac Pro to drive the second and third monitors in a three-monitor setup?
>
> **Answer: To run 3 monitors with this card - 2 of them need to be "active" on the display port connections.**
>
> I run the card with 2 display port monitors (an HP and DELL) and 1 DVI monitor - (A 1080p projector with an hdmi/dvi passive adapter). I'm doing this in both a 2010 and 2008 mac pro.
>
> I assume because of this, you can buy the active dual-link dvi/dp adapter and get the same results.
>
> But I can confirm you can't do this with a passive adapter.

Comment: I ordered two Active Mini-Display to DVI adapters today. They were 3rd party, ATI Gold Approved, and about the same cost as Apples. I will post and let everyone know if they work!

Comment: This works!!! Be sure they are ATI gold and the max resolution was exactly what I needed. No extra USB is needed either. Because they were 3rd party, they were only 35, which is the same as the Apple non-"active" dvi adapters.

Comment: Glad it helped, it is really something Apple did not mention this little tidbit...