# Mac Pro ATI 5770 with 3 monitors - what active adapters needed?

Tags: display, mac-pro

I just bought a Mac Pro 2010 with an ATI5770 that has 2 x Mini Display Port (DP) and 1 x DVI.

The current configuration is as follows:

- Mini DP A > passive HDMI adapter > 1920 LCD
- Mini DP B > passive HDMI adapter > 1920 LCD
- DVI > passive DVI to HDMI adapter > 1920 LCD

In this configuration, **only two out of the three monitors will work at any given time**.  From reading up on the topic, I understand that I'll need at least one **active adapter** in order to get all three monitors going together.

**What is the minimal number of active adapters I need?** i.e. do I need one or two, and on which port(s)? If that matters.

A recommendation for suitable non-Apple adapters would also be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question – [How to get 3 1900x1200 monitors working on a 2010 Mac Pro](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/56276/how-to-get-3-1900x1200-monitors-working-on-a-2010-mac-pro?rq=1) ?

Comment: I read that before, but I had to read it again to really follow.  So I need 2 x Active Mini DP to HDMI adapters?

Comment: I only have [two displays connected to my Mac Pro](http://theworklife.com/graham-miln/2013/07/09/fixing-mac-kernel-panic-ati-5770-and-nvidia-gt120-graphics-cards/). Hopefully someone with three displays will be along soon to provide an definite answer; otherwise a trip to an Apple Store Genius might be wise.

Comment: well I just ordered 2 x active Mini DP adapters - so I can let you know on Friday ;)

Comment: Please do formally answer and close this question when you know. I hope they work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirmed: for this to work you need two (not just one) *active* adapters on the Mini DisplayPorts.  When shopping around, the adapters may also be referred to as `Eyefinity` compatible.  You don't *have* to buy genuine adapters - I am using two of the cheaper ones.